# Having Git with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, git, azure-devops

Image I have a UWP app that I added it to my VSTS and I am committing my changes through Git:
- I am editing my project, when I am happy with it, I am committing my changes to my master branch.

Now, how can I have the same scenario for a WordPress project?
- I am editing my project, on a local repository, e.g. using WAMP, when I am happy with it, I am committing my changes to my master branch, which is my live website.

- If it is possible, is it efficient? If not, what is the most efficient way to use Git on a website project in your opinion?

Answer (score -1):

Somebody did it through CI/CD with Microsoft DevOps. [Part 1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deploying-wordpress-application-using-vsts-and-azure-part-one/) and [Part 2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deploying-wordpress-application-using-visual-studio-team-services-and-azure-part-two/).